Agora Flutter SDK: Video call not defaulting to speaker when initialized
I'm developing a video calling feature in my Flutter app using the Agora SDK. I'm encountering an issue where the call audio doesn't default to the speaker when the call is initialized. Here's what I've tried:
await _engine.setEnableSpeakerphone(true);
I'm calling this method right after joining the channel:
agoraEventHandlers: AgoraRtcEventHandlers(
          onLocalUserRegistered: (uid, userAccount) {},
          onJoinChannelSuccess: (connection, int elapsed) async {
           
            try{
              await client?.engine.setEnableSpeakerphone(true);

            }catch(e){
              logMsg.add("setEnableSpeakerphone : ${e.toString()}");
              showSnackMsgSnackBar();
            }
            try{
              isSpeaker = (await client?.engine.isSpeakerphoneEnabled()) ?? false;
              setState(() {});
              if (!isSpeaker) {
                Fluttertoast.showToast(
                  msg: "Turn on Speaker",
                  toastLength: Toast.LENGTH_SHORT,
                  gravity: ToastGravity.BOTTOM,
                  timeInSecForIosWeb: 2,
                );
              }
            }catch(e){
              logMsg.add("isSpeakerphoneEnabled : ${e.toString()}");
              showSnackMsgSnackBar();

            }
          },

However, when the call starts, it's still using the earpiece instead of the speaker. I've also tried:

Can you update the agora plugin to the latest
late RtcEngine _engine;
_engine.registerEventHandler(
  RtcEngineEventHandler(
    onJoinChannelSuccess: (RtcConnection connection, int elapsed) {
        try{
          await _engine.setEnableSpeakerphone(true);

        }catch(e){
          logMsg.add("setEnableSpeakerphone : ${e.toString()}");
          showSnackMsgSnackBar();
        }
        try{
          isSpeaker = (await client?.engine.isSpeakerphoneEnabled()) ?? false;
          setState(() {});
          if (!isSpeaker) {
            Fluttertoast.showToast(
              msg: "Turn on Speaker",
              toastLength: Toast.LENGTH_SHORT,
              gravity: ToastGravity.BOTTOM,
              timeInSecForIosWeb: 2,
            );
          }
        }catch(e){
          logMsg.add("isSpeakerphoneEnabled : ${e.toString()}");
          showSnackMsgSnackBar();

        }
    },
   
  ),
);

